# record visible according to the status

Tags: visualforce, community

When the pet’s status is “New” or “Evaluating”, the record must only be visible to the veterinarian and the assigned director.

Once the assigned director has set a pet’s status to “Available”, that pet must be visible to all users.

Once a pet has been adopted (i.e., the status of the pet is equal to “Adopted”) the pet record must only be visible to the veterinarian and the assigned director.

Household information must only be visible to the director and staff.

Adoption requests are only visible by staff and directors.

Comment: Are the Pet, Household and Adoption request all custom objects? How are they related (Master:Detail or Lookup)? Are you using VF pages rather than standard page layouts?

Comment: yes these fields are custom object and it is related using lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Organization Wide Default for the Object to **Private**.

The next step would be to assign **Roles** to the users to share the records.

Then in Sharing Settings, add the Sharing Rules based on the criteria you mentioned to share with the relevant users (using the roles assigned).